# Edit Review Queue on Stack Overflow: Can I flag a user?

Tags: support, review

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477611/zogthedog) is making several poor quality wiki tag edits.

If you look at [his reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477611/zogthedog?tab=reputation), they've acquired over 100 points making these edits over the last couple of days. Somehow their edits have slipped past the review stage: the ones I have inspected are of sufficiently poor quality to be rolled back.

How can I flag this for moderator attention? Is there a way to do this from the review queue screens?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to flag it directly from the review queue. The user also doesn't have any Qs or As so I think meta is appropriate action as of today.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Maybe that is not a good candidate for duplicate when the situation here is the opposite to that post?

Comment: @Antony opposite how? In this post: "This user is making several **poor quality wiki tag edits**". In the other post: "This particular user seems to be on a tag wiki editing spree ... which are **very trivial and offer very less information**". Looks the same to me.

Comment: As the OP I concur this is duplicate.

Comment: @Bathsheba cheers, you can add your own close vote. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Maybe you should take a look at the answer to the other question as well?

Comment: @Antony I went over that user edits and some are indeed helpful while many get rejected. "I see no reason to stop this user" is also valid here, when enough edits will be rejected he'll get auto ban for 7 days. The system works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, what one would do is flag one of the user's posts with the "other" type, and explain there.

However, as this user has no posts, this is not possible. Instead, it is preferred that you send [an email to the team](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact). There is no need to do this now as moderators will see this post; however, email is preferred, as it does not call a  specific user out in public.

Comment: The other workaround is to flag one of your own posts, making sure to explain that you're not the problem, that editor over there is.

Comment: @mich Ooh, that's also a good solution. Hadn't thought of that one.